# Formatting of the BibLaTeX citation key

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I've got a BibLaTeX database which is set up to be printed with `alphabetic` style. That results in the wanted characters, but not in the wanted formatting. I would like to have those keys (shown as enumeration items in the bibliography and in every citation) typeset as `\scshape`. How can I achieve that?

[image: biblatex problem]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxbibnames=1,maxcitenames=1,defernumbers,%
    doi=false,isbn=false,clearlang=false,backref=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@ONLINE{text:source,
    author={B. Obby},
    title={Sources today},
    url={http://www.example.com},
    urldate={2017-02-20},}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Text with citation: \autocite{text:source}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the field format.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxbibnames=1,maxcitenames=1,defernumbers,%
    doi=false,isbn=false,clearlang=false,backref=false]{biblatex}



\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\textsc{#1}}


\begin{document}

Text with citation: \autocite{herrmann}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]